# Once I've added Global Resource languages, how do I give client option which language to choose?

Tags: asp.net, .net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, localization

I have added 3 additional languages (fr, es-mx, de) to English in my company's website, and they're all working fine.  I followed the [MSDN walkthrough on creating localization](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fw69ke6f.aspx).

I'm using Visual Studio 2010 / VB / dot-net 4.0 and I already have in my top line on all of my pages, this:

```
  <%@ Page Title="USS Products & Services" Language="VB" MasterPageFile="~/products/products.Master" AutoEventWireup="false"
CodeFile="default.aspx.vb" Inherits="default" culture="auto" meta:resourcekey="PageResource1" uiculture="auto" %>
```

I have 4 global resource (.resx) files in my global_apps directory.  But what if I don't want just the browser alone to detect their language?  I want to give them the option of choosing their own language.

How do I give the client the option between 4 flags -- 1 for each language -- and let them choose?  Or maybe a rollover sitemap type of effect, where they can mouse over a language and choose it?  Any help would be appreciated!  Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try this simple method:
I've defined the languages in a dropdownlist and have a button select

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="ddlCulture" DataTextField="DisplayName" DataValueField="Name"
         runat="server" >
        <asp:ListItem Value="es-MX">Spanish</asp:ListItem>
        <asp:ListItem Value="en-US">English</asp:ListItem>
    </asp:DropDownList>
<asp:Button ID="btnSelect" Text="Select" runat="server" OnClick="btnSelect_Click" />
```

Now Code:

```
protected void btnSelect_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
   {
        Session["uiculture"] = ddlCulture.SelectedValue;
        Session["culture"] = ddlCulture.SelectedValue;
        Response.Redirect(Request.Path);
   }

    protected override void InitializeCulture()
    {
      if(Session["culture"]!=null)
        UICulture=Session["culture"].ToString();
    }
```

**Update**: Sorry I forgot the override keyword. Now included it should work.

By the way, you're using VB, sorry I'vent seen this. The equivalent code is:

```
 Protected Sub btnSelect_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs)
    Session("uiculture") = ddlCulture.SelectedValue
    Session("culture") = ddlCulture.SelectedValue
    Response.Redirect(Request.Path)
End Sub
Protected Overrides Sub InitializeCulture()
    If Not Session("culture") Is Nothing Then
        UICulture = Session("culture").ToString()
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Hi Nuux.  Thank you for responding.  I feel dumb for asking, but where would I put the 2nd block of code you suggested?  I know where to put the button.  But the coding?  Again, appreciate your help!

Comment: I put the code at the bottom of the page, and there were no build errors.  I tried clicking Spanish and English, etc., but it doesn't change the language on the web browser.  And it puts this at the top of the page:  protected void btnSelect_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) { Session["uiculture"] = ddlCulture.SelectedValue; Session["culture"] = ddlCulture.SelectedValue; Response.Redirect(Request.Path); } protected void InitializeCulture() { if(Session["culture"]!=null) UICulture=Session["culture"].ToString(); }

Comment: I updated the last method. So try. Where you place the method is no problem put it after the bttn event or any where in your code behind or between <script></script> tags. Let me know any progress. Thanks

Comment: Got it!  Thank you very much, Nuux!  It works perfectly!  This is great.  I'll put this on my home page and take things from there.  Thank you for your help and your patience -- I appreciate it!

Comment: Hey nuux, if you're still here, I'm just curious.  It works great for English, French, Spanish-Mexican, and German.  But when I do Swedish or Japanese, it says page not found and it won't refresh.  These are 2 languages I just added recently.  I'll retrace my steps to make sure I did them properly.

Comment: @JasonWeber: Check if you've the right resource file name and if you've passed the correct language and country codes. For complete list see [Culture Names](http://www.csharp-examples.net/culture-names/). Otherwise, if two+ languages work why not others, just a matter of settings I mean passing and using the right resource file

Comment: Yes, I had sv-SV for my Sweden and I changed it to just sv and it works fine now.  I apologize for being a bother, but thanks a bunch for your help Nuux -- you've really helped a ton!

Comment: Now I just have to figure out how to KEEP the language on the selected language, so they can view the rest of the website in that language.  I'll post another question on how to get it to work in master pages, and I'll reference your name