# Manually set UICulture in ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, localization, culture

I'm using .resx files to localise a website. Normally the appropriate file is selected automatically, but I'd also like to allow to select it manually. To do that, I store a field in the database. Where and how should I assign it to the UICulture to change the page language?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might help you:

[how do I give client option which language to choose?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8949988/once-ive-added-global-resource-languages-how-do-i-give-client-option-which-lan/8951100#8951100)
[Once localized with .resx files, how to enable client to view entire website in their language?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8965927/once-localized-with-resx-files-how-to-enable-client-to-view-entire-website-in/8968658#8968658)

For more search [SO](http://stackoverflow.com), you should find different flavors methods as how to do it.